# Rotating UIView and background to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

The initial root view controller is 9 (3x3) buttons with a custom background in portrait mode.  When the device is rotated into landscape mode the last row of buttons (of course) are cut off and the background (which is 320x480) doesn't fill the width of the screen.

What is the proper way of handling this?  Do I need to move and resize the buttons myself?  Do I have multiple Nibs?  How do I resize/rotate the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the [auto-resizing masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) on the buttons to have flexible margins in all directions they should reposition themselves appropriately when you rotate the device. You can do this either in code, or in Interface Builder (*which has a nice little simulator demonstrating the effect*)

With regards the background, what I prefer to do is to make the image the combination of the maximum proportions of each orientation, and then center it. For instance, make your image 480 x 480, make the view that houses it the same size and then use the appropriate auto-resizing masks to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and/or deviceDidRotateSelector in your viewController to reposition / layout & scale your views programmatically as you require.